# How do I combine a field from multiple rows into a delimited list?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with many (30+) columns and ~250k rows. I want to take three columns (GroupId, Name, and Species), group them by the GroupId, and join together the Species field from multiple rows into one.

For example, the following data:

```
1     NameA     Cat
2     NameA     Dog
3     NameA     BigBird
4     NameB     Chicken
6     NameC     Wolf
7     NameC     Lion
```

The desired results:

```
1     NameA     Cat,Dog,BigBird
2     NameB     Chicken
3     NameC     Wolf,Lion
```

This SQL groups the data together:

```
SELECT GROUPID, NAME, SPECIES,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by GROUPID order by SPECIES) r
from TableName;
```

How do I combine the Species field for each group and create a field with a comma-separated list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm#SQLRF30030) since Oracle 11g:

```
select NAME
     , listagg(SPECIES, ', ') within group (order by GROUPID) as "SPECIES"
from TableName
group by NAME
```

If you want only unique values:

```
select NAME
     , listagg(SPECIES, ', ') within group (order by GROUPID) as "SPECIES"
from (
   select distinct NAME
        , SPECIES
   from TableName
) t
group by NAME
```

or `wm_concat()`:

```
select NAME
     , wm_concat(distinct SPECIES) as "SPECIES"
from TableName
group by NAME
```

Comment: How do you remove the duplicates in "SPECIES"? For example, I have "BigBird, BigBird, BigBird, BigBird". If the result is four rows containing the same species, I only want it to appear once. Seems like a distinct is needed but I'm not sure how it fits in.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL prefer this query:

```
select 
    row_number() over(order by name) as group_id, name,
    stuff( (select ',' + species  
            from tbl_species s1
            where tbl_species.name = s1.name
            for xml path('') ), 1, 1, '') as species
 from 
     tbl_species 
 group by 
     name
```

https://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stuff-and-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation/

You can refer this site to know more about `stuff` and `for xml path`